# Marketing Cloud SQL Query - Show All Send Stats by Subscriber Across All Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

Just like the below SQL to see who bounced in Journey Send Emails, can expand this to include everyone? If they've bounced or not?

```
select 
s.JobID, 
s.ListID, 
s.BatchID, 
s.EventDate as 'SendTime', 
b.EventDate as 'BounceTime', 
su.EmailAddress,
j.JourneyName, 
j.VersionNumber, 
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName' 
from [_Sent] s 
join [_JourneyActivity] ja 
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID 
join [_Journey] j 
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID 
join [_Sent] b 
on s.JobID = b.JobID 
and s.ListID = b.ListID 
and s.BatchID = b.BatchID 
and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID 
join [_Subscribers] su 
on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID 
where ja.ActivityType in ('EMAIL','EMAILV2') 
and b.SubscriberID is not null
```

Comment: I've updated my answer since you updated your question, but I'm unsure what you current issue is, please add clarity to your question/issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried joining the bounce data view on Job ID/Subscriber Id? 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5

Comment: That worked. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I believe you are now trying to get bounce data, for all subscribers even if they didn't bounce. I would update your query with a left join.

```
SELECT
s.JobID, 
s.ListID, 
s.BatchID, 
s.EventDate AS 'SendTime', 
b.EventDate AS 'BounceTime', 
su.EmailAddress,
j.JourneyName, 
j.VersionNumber, 
ja.ActivityName AS 'EmailName' 
FROM [_Sent] s 
JOIN [_JourneyActivity] ja 
ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID 
JOIN [_Journey] j 
ON ja.VersionID = j.VersionID 
LEFT JOIN [_Bounce] b 
ON s.JobID = b.JobID 
AND s.ListID = b.ListID 
AND s.BatchID = b.BatchID 
AND s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID 
JOIN [_Subscribers] su 
ON s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID 
WHERE ja.ActivityType in ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
```